# Amazon Login with Android - Multiple API Keys

Tags: android, login-with-amazon

My question is as follows:

I am using Amazon Login for my Android app.
I need multiple Amazon API Keys, one for production, the other for debugging.
This is different then having one in the Amazon store, and my debugging one not in the store. Seeing as I will need to use 2 separate api_key.txt files. How can I go about providing two separate api_key.txt files based on the apk produced from my app (debug/production)

Thanks

**Note**

Using either the production api key or debugging one alone works perfectly fine if paired with the correct apk (debug.apk vs release.apk) the issue is combing the two into the same project continuously.

Comment: Does the Amazon SDK require that you have a txt file with the key or can you set it in code? What build system are you using? For example the Gradle build system that comes with Android Studio is very powerful and supports multiple build types (debug, release etc.) as well as multiple build flavors (Integration, Staging, Production in my use case). I use build configuration values for API keys.

Comment: Amazon requires a txt file. And I have gradle, using two different build variants, debug and release. I guess my question would be then how to have 2 different text files with these build variants, but alias them both to be api_key.txt (The file name has to be exact)

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you're placing the `api_key.txt` file in the `/src/main/assets/` directory, you can use a build type specific directory structure like so:

- src/main/assets/... (all other assets not specific to a build type)
- src/debug/assets/api_key.txt
- src/release/assets/api_key.txt

Gradle will take the appropriate file for the appropriate build type.

Comment: Thanks @darnmason! I haven't tested this yet but this is probably what I should be doing! I appreciate the help! Once I test it later this week I'll mark it as correct